# How to delay .trigger('click') with overlay from jquery tools

Tags: jquery, ajax, overlay

I am using Jquery tools, overlay effect and want to close it, if JSON response is OK, but i want to do it with a delay.

```
  $.ajax({
                //bla bla
                success: function(data){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        if (obj.status=='OK')
                        {
                            $('#status').text('bla bla');
                            jQuery('.close').trigger('click');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#status').text('bla bla');                       
                        }
                    }
            });
```

so this - jQuery('.close').trigger('click'); must be executed after some time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`setTimeout()` is a native JavaScript function designed for this purpose.

```
setTimeout(function () {
   jQuery('.close').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

The last number there is the delay time in milliseconds.

Comment: I -would- be thinking, the very same (syntactic sugar..) would be possible by $('#nivo').delay(5000).load(

Comment: @Fronker, it wouldn't work with the delay().load(...), because the .load() doesn't care about the .delay() function, same as .show(), for example. Only functions that use the jQuery queue would be able to use effects of the delay().

Answer (score 6):

use setTimeout:

delay here is 1 second (1000 ms)

```
$.ajax({
                //bla bla
                success: function(data){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        if (obj.status =='OK')
                    {
                        $('#status').text('bla bla');
                        setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.close').trigger('click');},1000);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#status').text('bla bla');                       
                    }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score -4):

Not tested.

```
jQuery('.close').delay(500).trigger('click');
```

Comment: `.delay()` only works with effects in jQuery that use the effects queue. `.trigger()` isn't one of those.

Comment: Like what TelegramSam says, you have to use the setTimeout function for this.